Kendall tau-c can never be 1?
I have one system that scores on a 5-point scale (4=very good, 3=good, 2=average, 1=bad, 0=very bad). Now, I want to turn them into binary scores, so I want to set a threshold and then convert them into 1/0 scores. My intuition is that the 5-point scale scores and the binary scores should always be perfectly rank-correlated, i.e. a rank correlation of 1. (Information loss is another thing.)
I use the Kendall tau-c, since it is designed for measuring the rank correlation between different number of possible outcomes (5 vs 2). But I found the correlations are not identical and far from 1 in the following simplest examples.
print(scipy.stats.kendalltau([0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], variant='c'))  # 1 if >= 4 and 0 o.w.
print(scipy.stats.kendalltau([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], variant='c'))  # 1 if >= 3 and 0 o.w.
print(scipy.stats.kendalltau([0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], variant='c'))  # 1 if >= 2 and 0 o.w.
print(scipy.stats.kendalltau([0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], variant='c'))  # 1 if >= 1 and 0 o.w.

outputs
SignificanceResult(statistic=0.64, pvalue=0.15729920705028516)
SignificanceResult(statistic=0.96, pvalue=0.0832645166635504)
SignificanceResult(statistic=0.96, pvalue=0.0832645166635504)
SignificanceResult(statistic=0.64, pvalue=0.15729920705028516)

It seems to suggest that no matter how I tune the threshold or design the binary converter, I can never make Kendall tau-c reach 1. I totally understand that Kendal tau-b should not be 1 in this case, but my understanding is that the goal for the rectangular adjustment is to correct cases like this so that the correlation can reach 1 in the perfect case.
Is this a bug or a feature? And, are there some other rank correlation variants that can produce a correlation of 1 in this case?

The paper where Stuart defines Kendall's $\tau_c$ shows that

he's trying to get the range as close as possible to $\pm 1$
he doesn't think it's feasible to get exactly that

He writes "When $n$ is not a multiple of $m$, [the denominator] remains an upper bound, but cannot be attained. This is a quite unimportant deficiency in practice, when $n$ is often large and $m$ very small"
